# Django (SQLite) - cannot access foreign key - no such column - custom sql

Tags: django, sqlite, foreign-keys

I am getting "no such column" whenever I try to access a foreign key.  Here is a model:

```
class PerkLevel(models.Model):
    perk_id = models.ForeignKey('Perk', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='perk_id')
    perk_level = models.IntegerField(default=1, choices=PERK_LEVELS)
    perk_desc = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'pl'
```

When I try to execute a simple query like this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT perk_id FROM pl")
```

I get "no such column: perk_id."  How can I get the foreign key when writing my own sql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django adds its own `_id` to the end of foreign keys. In this case, I would use `perk_id_id`.

Comment: ... which is one of the reasons why you shouldn't use `_id` in the ForeignKey name in the first place. Just call it `perk`, then the db column will be `perk_id`.

Comment: I wish Django would not mess with the name I chose.  As far as I'm concerned, I did it right the first time!  I stumbled upon this solution randomly after trying many other things cause I vaguely remembered reading about an '_id' in the docs.